# How to save tokenization result for each file in a new separate text file?

Tags: python

I have 349 text file. I use the following code to read and tokenize all of them.

```
import glob
path = "C:\\texts\\*.txt"
for file in files:
   with open (file) as in_file, open ("C:\\texts\\file_tokens.txt", 'w') as out_file:
       for line in in_file:
           words = line.split()
           for word in words:
               out_file.write(word)
               out_file.write("\n")
```

This code save the result (all tokens) in one file (file_tokens.txt). How can I save the tokens of each file in a new .txt file? I mean I want 349 files in output as each contains the tokens of each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from os import path
base_path = "C:\\texts\\*.txt"  #RENAMED
for file in files:
    with open (file) as in_file:
        with open(path.join(base_path,"%s_tokenized.txt" % file)) as out_file:  #ATTENTION
            for line in in_file:
                words = line.split()
                for word in words:
                out_file.write(word)
                out_file.write("\n")
```

You create a new file with a name specific to the current file you're proccessing. In this example it's `($file_name)_tokenized.txt`.

`path.join` is used to output the file to the correct directory. I.e

```
>>> path.join("~/Documents","out.txt")
'~/Documents/out.txt'
```

Comment: this code worked for me after I made 2 changes; 
import glob;
from os import path;
base_path = "C:\\texts\\*.txt";
files = glob.glob(base_path)

Answer (score 0):

Give each of the output files a different name.

Comment: No. Pretty much all of your code has been written by SO users answering your series of questions. You do not know how this code works, and cannot figure out what it will do. Then you come back here and ask your next question when the code you don't understand doesn't behave as you hoped. If you cannot work out how to adapt your code to create more than one output file, how will writing the code for you help?

Comment: You should invest some of your own time to do some research, take some tutorials, and work out how the code you have posted actually works.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. As you follow my questions, you might see in my first question (in the first question, I use answers to write a better code even!), I mentioned that I am new to text and python. I don't see anything wrong to learn how to code with python in this way. If I didn't read tutorials. I couldn't develop these few lines of code even to this level :)